# Email Password Change Notifications to Different User in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have a Server 2019 DC, the users on this machine are to change passwords every 90-days. When we're coming up on that change, users receive emails warning them of this fact. I have a few ghost users that aren't assigned to people, I don't even think these users have email boxes (which is hosted through 365. What I need to do is make sure that a designated person gets those ghost user password change notifications.

Basically:

GhostUser@domain.com password change emails need to be sent to SupervisorUser@domain.com.

How do you recommend I set this up?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot assign those users to a single email address linked to a service account (which has it's own  email)? Forwarding rule might be appropriate in this case.

Comment: What solution are you using to send Password Change Notifications? Is it a script?

Comment: @jfrmilner,

A good question, I'm not sure.  I'm a new to this ecosystem and cutting my teeth on AD.  When I look in the GPO under User Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts, Logon/Logoff are empty.  Same with Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts\Startup/Shutdown.

Can PS scripts be run via Task Scheduler?  I poked around in there and didn't see anything obvious.  Where else might I look?

Comment: @Ramhound

If I understand you correctly,  GhostUser@domain.com would have its own email address in Exchange and we'd simply set up a rule in there to forward all of those emails to SupervisorUser@domain.com?